# Get a list of notes - ASP.net webforms

Tags: evernote

I am trying to get a list of notes from Evernote but I only was able to get the "oauth_verifier". I have tried the SDK but I think it only works with winforms applications.

Which information can I use to solve my requirement?

Comment: Are you using C#? Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332506/how-to-get-oauth-working-with-dotnetopenauth-and-evernote) will somewhat help?

Comment: Yes, I am using C#.
I am going to check the link, thanks!